# PHP eBay API revise Item using Business Policies

Tags: php, ebay-api

I am using the eBay API and @davidtstadler's [SDK](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php) to revise ebay listings.

I am using eBay business policies for payment methods, shipping costs and returns. I can retrieve my business policy id's using BusinessPoliciesManagementService but how do I **revise an item to use the policies** for payment, shipping and returns.

I cannot find any examples in the API documentation.

Comment: [Looks like](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-examples/blob/master/business-policies-management/README.md) the SDK only allows you to retrieve business polices, not set them.

Comment: I don't want to set them - I want to use them when I list or revise an item.

Comment: Use the ID's that you got back from the business policies and pass them to the PaymentProfileID, ReturnProfileID, ShippingProfileID fields when revising/adding your items.

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/AddFixedPriceItem.html#Request.Item.SellerProfiles

Comment: thanks david, do you have a code sample, $item->SellerProfiles->SellerPaymentProfile->PaymentProfileID=1234567890; returns an error when used in reviseitem

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: my mistake was not creating the new type object for each profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to set Business Policy ID's for Payment, Returns and Shipping is

```
    // Business PROFILES
    $item->SellerProfiles = new Types\SellerProfilesType();

    // PAYMENT
    $item->SellerProfiles->SellerPaymentProfile = new Types\SellerPaymentProfileType();
    $item->SellerProfiles->SellerPaymentProfile->PaymentProfileID = 1234567890;
    // RETURNS
    $item->SellerProfiles->SellerReturnProfile = new Types\SellerReturnProfileType();
    $item->SellerProfiles->SellerReturnProfile->ReturnProfileID = 1234567890;
    // SHIPPING
    $item->SellerProfiles->SellerShippingProfile = new Types\SellerShippingProfileType();
    $item->SellerProfiles->SellerShippingProfile->ShippingProfileName = 1234567890;
```